# Rewrite folder to act like it's root

Tags: .htaccess

Hello I have a git repository that I clone into my document root. The problem is that it is creating directory. What I want is to write `.htaccess` file to make sure that that folder will act like root.

Example: `/website` => `/`; `/website/foo.html#somedata=3` => `/foo.html#somedata=3`.

I've tried this code below but all it does is redirects me to `/website`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /website$1 [L]
```

Comment: Do you also want requests directly into `/website/foo` to be redirected  to `/foo` in the browser address bar to hide the existence of `/website`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^((?!website/).*)$ /website/$1 [L,NC]
```